# Is there a way of accessing SQL Server database directly from PostgreSQL(PgAdmin)?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have an application that is directly connected to Postgresql database, I need to retrieve certain values from an external SQL Server database.

Is there a way I can send a select statement to SQL Server from postgresql, and get back the results?

Comment: PostgreSQL and pgAdmin are different thing.  Please fix your title if your question is not about pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

yes - you can use foreign table on MS SQL Server

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3663/sql-server-and-postgresql-foreign-data-wrapper-configuration-part-3/

https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw